# Menu "Buffers" not listing

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I recently upgraded to emacs 24 on ubuntu. I've noticed that for emacs 24, when I click on the buffer menu, it only displays *GNU EMACS* %, *scratch* and *messages* *, where as before on emacs 23, all my buffers were visible. How do i fix this?

Comment: The buffers seem to be cycled around a bit, are your buffers listed if you switch to one of your files?

Comment: If you are referring to the `uninteresting` buffers that have a space at the beginning of the buffer name, then yes the current default behavior in Emacs is to hide those buffers.  One option would be for you to write your own function using `buffer-list` to display everything including the `uninteresting buffers`.  For example:  `(defun jon-buffer-list () (interactive) (message "Buffer List -- all:  %s" (buffer-list)))`

Comment: Perhaps you could include a screenshot of what your buffers menu shows when you have two text files open?

Answer (score 0):

When you start emacs, the Buffers Menu will only display GNU Emacs, scratch, and messages' buffers, unless another buffer is opened.

If you upgraded emacs on ubuntu, make sure all dependencies are met and installed. And all the libraries are installed as well. The menu bar depends on the GTK libraries. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#X-Resources for further info.

As a last resort, `M-x customize-group` then `menu`, scroll down to `Buffers Menu Max Size` and change the value accordingly. By default is at 10.